# Is there an equivalent for the Zip function in Clojure Core or Contrib?

Tags: clojure

In Clojure, I want to combine two lists to give a list of pairs,

```
> (zip '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))  
((1 4) (2 5) (3 6))
```

In Haskell or Ruby the function is called *zip*. Implementing it is not difficult, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing a function in Core or Contrib.

There is a [zip](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.zip-api.html) namespace in Core, but it is [described](http://clojure.org/other_libraries) as providing access to the Zipper functional technique, which does not appear to be what I am after.

Is there an equivalent function for combining 2 or more lists, in this way, in Core?

If there is not, is it because there is an idiomatic approach that renders the function unneeded?

Answer (score 247, accepted):

```
(map vector '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
```

does what you want:

```
=> ([1 4] [2 5] [3 6])
```

Haskell needs a collection of `zipWith` (`zipWith3`, `zipWith4`, ...) functions, because they all need to be of a specific *type*; in particular, the number of input lists they accept needs to be fixed. (The `zip`, `zip2`, `zip3`, ... family can be regarded as a specialisation of the `zipWith` family for the common use case of tupling).

In contrast, Clojure and other Lisps have good support for variable arity functions; `map` is one of them and can be used for "tupling" in a manner similar to Haskell's

```
zipWith (\x y -> (x, y))
```

The idiomatic way to build a "tuple" in Clojure is to construct a short vector, as displayed above.

(Just for completeness, note that Haskell with some basic extensions does allow variable arity functions; using them requires a good understanding of the language, though, and the vanilla Haskell 98 probably doesn't support them at all, thus fixed arity functions are preferrable for the standard library.)

Comment: Note that this behaves differently than `zip` when the collections are not the same length. Ruby will continue processing and supply `nil`s for the shorter collection, whereas Clojure will stop processing once one of the collections is exhausted.

Comment: @NateW. That is good to note, thanks. In Haskell `zip` behaves like Clojure's `map` in this respect.

Answer (score 28):

```
(partition 2 (interleave '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))) 
=> ((1 4) (2 5) (3 6))
```

or more generally

```
(defn zip [& colls]
  (partition (count colls) (apply interleave colls)))

(zip '( 1 2 3) '(4 5 6))           ;=> ((1 4) (2 5) (3 6))

(zip '( 1 2 3) '(4 5 6) '(2 4 8))  ;=> ((1 4 2) (2 5 4) (3 6 8))
```

Answer (score 15):

```
(map vector [1 2 3] [4 5 6])
```

Answer (score 12):

to give you exactly what you wanted, mapping `list` across the two lists will give you a list of lists like in your example. I think that many Clojurians would tend to use vectors for this though it will work with anything. and the inputs do not need to be the same type. map creates seqs from them and then maps the seqs so any seq'able input will work fine.

```
(map list '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
(map list  [1 2 3] '(4 5 6))
(map hash-map  '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
(map hash-set  '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
```

Comment: I think you mean hash-map and hash-set instead of map and set.

Answer (score 3):

The built-in way would simply be the function 'interleave':

```
(interleave [1 2 3 4] [5 6 7 8]) => [1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8]
```

Comment: to achieve the goal of the OP you should add `(partition 2 (interleave [1 2 3 4][5 6 7 8]))`

Comment: yes - It appears I didn't look at the OP's desired output too closely.

Answer (score -1):

There is a function called zipmap, that may have the similar effect,
    (zipmap `(1 2 3)`(4 5 6))
The ouput is as fllows:
    {3 6, 2 5, 1 4}

Comment: zipmap returns you a map, which does not guarantee the order

Comment: That was my first thought, too. Nice try though.

Comment: While this is true, you already have the order of xs (and therefore the "order" of `(zipmap xs ys)`).

Answer (score -4):

#(apply map list %) transposes a matrix just like the Python zip* function. As a macro definition:

user=> (defmacro py-zip [lst] `(apply map list ~lst))

#'user/py-zip

user=> (py-zip '((1 2 3 4) (9 9 9 9) (5 6 7 8)))

((1 9 5) (2 9 6) (3 9 7) (4 9 8))

user=> (py-zip '((1 9 5) (2 9 6) (3 9 7) (4 9 8)))

((1 2 3 4) (9 9 9 9) (5 6 7 8))

Comment: How is this better than just using 'map'? And what's the point of a macro here?