# How do I merge two lists into coordinates?

Tags: clojure

If I have two arbitrary length lists of the same [arbitrary] length, X and Y, how do I merge them such that

((X1 Y1) (X2 Y2) ... (Xn Yn)) ?

e.g.
List X:
(1 3 4 5 6 ... N) 
and List Y:
(5 13 1 4 9 ... N)

how do I merge them to create something like

((1 5) (3 13) (4 1) (5 4) (6 9) ... ) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an equivalent for the Zip function in Clojure Core or Contrib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588227/is-there-an-equivalent-for-the-zip-function-in-clojure-core-or-contrib)

Comment: Not really a duplicate - it's a different context and co-ordinates are different from zipped pairs in various interesting ways

Comment: In what way is it different? It looks exactly the same to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(map list [1 2 3] [4 5 6])
=> ((1 4) (2 5) (3 6))
```

Though for coordinates, I'd use (map vector ...) instead:

```
(map vector [1 2 3] [4 5 6])
=> ([1 4] [2 5] [3 6])
```

Comment: can you explain why you prefer vector for coordinates?

Comment: I would prefer vectors for this, because I personally like `(v 0)` and `(v 1)` notation for accessing the X and Y components directly from the vector, which is useful in short expressions. The alternatives with lists/seqs are less appealing.