# Shuffle by merging lists in Clojure

Tags: clojure

How does one write a function to split a list and then merge it back together such that the resulting list represents the shuffle of a deck?

The list `(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)` should end up as `(1 6 2 7 3 8 4 9 5 10)`

Is there a way to use `split-at` or `reduce` or some other function to achieve this?

So far I'm here:

```
(defn shuffle [cards] 
  (split-at (/ (count cards) 2) cards)
)
```

Comment: What I think you want is to zip the two lists together in this case.  But if you're talking about shuffling, then shouldn't it be more random?  There's no guarantee of a one-to-one zipping during card shuffling.

Comment: What you describe is a perfect [riffle shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling#Riffle). Perhaps you could edit the question accordingly.

Comment: You should probably use `quot` rather than `/` to get the integer quotient: for example, `(split-at 3.5 cards)` isn't entirely clear. In fact, `split-at` always rounds down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(apply interleave (split-at 5 (range 1 11)))
```

(1 6 2 7 3 8 4 9 5 10)

Comment: Works perfectly. This is the cleanest answer

Answer (score 3):

Clojure has an excellent selection of sequence functions.

```
user> (range 1 11)
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
user> (apply mapcat list (split-at 5 (range 1 11)))
(1 6 2 7 3 8 4 9 5 10)
```

You can get an overview at [the clojure cheatsheet](http://clojure.org/cheatsheet), it's a little out of date but mostly still relevant, and gives a good overview of the Clojure basics.

Comment: Ah `mapcat`, I always forget about you… (+1).

Comment: Don't forget interleave!

Answer (score 1):

Split like you already have, then [zip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2588227/211563) the two halves together and flatten:

```
(defn shuffle [cards]
  (->> cards
    (split-at (/ (count cards) 2))
    (apply map list)
    (flatten)))

(shuffle '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)) ;=> (1 6 2 7 3 8 4 9 5 10)
```

Of course if you want a “truly” random shuffle, use [`clojure.core/shuffle`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/shuffle).

Comment: `flatten` is almost always the wrong thing, if the input has any structure, `flatten` is likely to denature that structure, and to render the output irrelevant.

Comment: @noisesmith Yea, of course here it could’ve been just `apply concat`, or `mapcat` as you have.

Answer (score 0):

A general solution is

```
(defn riffle [s]
  (let [v (vec s), c (quot (count v) 2)]
    (interleave (subvec v 0 c) (subvec v c))))
```

In this case

```
(riffle '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
; (1 6 2 7 3 8 4 9 5 10)
```